# Get dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am targeting links with getElementsByTagName

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

It works for all links. However, if the link is dynamically loaded, it does not work.

I am loading new content with ajax (load more), and it contains links. I need to target these links too.

Comment: `anchors` is a [live HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), so it should be updated with new content on the DOM.  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: That's weird, because I'm pretty sure that `getElementsByTagName` returns a live collection

Comment: Are you "in control" of the AJAX call? If you are, consider adding a `complete` or `success` callback that runs a function that does the document selection call again. Otherwise you could consider using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) to know when DOM changes are made and react appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

It should work the same no matter if the link was there at page load, or added dynamically later.

However, you should update your variable when new `<a>` tags are added.

```js
let links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log("There are " + links.length + " link");

//wait 1 second
setTimeout(function(){
  //add another link
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<a href='#4'>4</a>");
  
  //Update the variable
  links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  console.log("There are " + links.length + " link");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<a href="#1">1</a> <a href="#2">2</a> <a href="#3">3</a>
```